# PHP Parse error: Invalid numeric literal

Tags: php

A migrar para o PHP 7 estou recebendo o seguinte erro: `Invalid numeric literal`

Por exemplo: `$itau = new Conta(1620, 030818);`

O PHP vai retornar um erro

> Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in index.php on line 35

Como resolver esse problema caso eu precise que o `0` fique a esquerda?

Comment: Mande como string, aquele zero na frente deve ser um octal inválido.

Comment: [Já fizeram essa pergunta em outro tópico, vê se te ajuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735963/parse-error-invalid-numeric-literal)

Comment: Esse zero a esquerda já vem ou vc adiciona ele?

Comment: No caso do meu erro foi eu que adicionei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse erro acontece porque o número informado não é um octal válido, essa notação é conhecido por ter um zero a esquerda.

Passe o valor como uma string (adicionando aspas) e não como número.

Mude:

```
$itau = new Conta(1620, 030818);
```

Para:

```
$itau = new Conta(1620, '030818');
```